# Create a row with decimal number in rowspan

Tags: html, html-table

It's possible create this table with rowspan ??

```
|---------|---------|  
| 1       |4        |
|---------|         |
| 2       |---------| 
|---------|5        |
| 3       |         |
|---------|---------|
```

Every row inside the second column have 1.5 ?

I think that its possible play with the attribute 'height' or maybe create another table inside the second column...

But is it possibble only with rowspan or colspan?

Comment: It is possible.You have to create table within 2nd column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rowsapn must be an integer, but you can use

[image]

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. How does your code work?

Comment: If you check the rendered table, you can clearly see that it doesn't match the mockup.

Answer (score 2):

I've created two tables: main table and a sub table. Within main table, I've created 2 columns with 3 rows. These three for 1, 2, 3 in your example. And in the other column I've created another small table with one column and two rows.

```html
<table border=1 width='200' height='100' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
  <tr>
    <td width='100'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      <table border='1' width="100" cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' height='100%'>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This seems to be the only way to achieve the exact layout as desired in the mockup.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**
We cannot set rowspan in decimal values like 0.5.
So, make each cell's rowspan double so that 0.5 becomes 1 and 1.5 becomes 3 effectively.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <!-- ROW 1 -->
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1</td>
        <td rowspan="3">4</td>
      </tr>

      <!-- ROW 2 -->
      <tr>
      </tr>

      <!-- ROW 3 -->
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
      </tr>

      <!-- ROW 4 -->
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">5</td>
      </tr>

      <!-- ROW 5 -->
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">3</td>
      </tr>

      <!-- ROW 6 -->
      <tr>
      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is invalid HTML, as you can't have empty `tr`, and also the table doesn't render as wished in the mockup.