# How can we create 3/2 span? The span is meant to divide the column space into 2 rows in front of 3 rows (corresponding to the previous column)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to divide the space covering the XPath and XSL Transformations (as shown in the picture) into two rows whereas the previous columns are divided into three rows. I have used CSS but can not achieve what is desired in this example.

Row and Column spanning in HTML table

[image]

Here's what I wrote for everything except the 3/2 spanning

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan=3>Day</th>
    <th colspan=3>Seminar</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=2>Schedule</th>
    <th rowspan=2>Topic</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Begin</th>
    <th>End</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>Monday</td>
    <td style="background-color: #F8F6D1;" rowspan=2>8:00 a.m.</td>
    <td style="background-color:#BFB4F8;" rowspan=2>5:00 p.m.</td>
    <td>Introduction to XML</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=3>Tuesday</td>
    <td style="background-color: #F8F6D1;">8:00 a.m.</td>
    <td style="background-color: #F8F6D1;">11:00 a.m.</td>
    <td rowspan=2>XPath</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #F8F6D1;">11:00 a.m.</td>
    <td style="background-color: #C7F8D8;">2:00 p.m.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #C7F8D8;">2:00 p.m.</td>
    <td style="background-color:#BFB4F8;">5:00 p.m.</td>
    <td rowspan=1>XSL Transformations</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td style="background-color: #F8F6D1;">8:00 a.m.</td>
    <td style="background-color: #C7F8D8;">12:00 p.m.</td>
    <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No it isnt same. The image shows that XPath and X Transformations have equal height of 1.5 rowspan. But in his code one has height of 1 and other 2..

Comment: I dont think it is possible. You can use CSS Grids though to make that table.

Comment: If you are talking about that *Tuesday* row in your sample image - there are 6 rows there actually with `rowspan="6"` for the first column cell, `rowspan="2"` for the second column cells and `rowspan="3"` for the last one's.

Comment: Having posted your `<table>` into JS Fiddle ([demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u6qkfvma/)), it seems to work perfectly as you've posted it in your question (both with, and without, some minor aesthetic CSS).

Comment: @Jared I have tried using 6, 2, and 3 spans for the columns but still the third column displays XPath on two rows and XSL Transformations on 4 rows

Comment: @Jared here's what it displays even after 6-2-3 span: https://jsfiddle.net/0wsfpytL/

Comment: I was wrong, its a 4-row section actually. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'Tuesday' block gonna be like this:

```
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='4'>Tuesday</td>
    <td style="background-color: #F8F6D1;">8:00 a.m.</td>
    <td style="background-color: #F8F6D1;">11:00 a.m.</td>
    <td rowspan='2'>XPath</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #F8F6D1;" rowspan="2">11:00 a.m.</td>
    <td style="background-color: #C7F8D8;" rowspan="2">2:00 p.m.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='2'>XSL Transformations</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #C7F8D8;">2:00 p.m.</td>
    <td style="background-color:#BFB4F8;">5:00 p.m.</td>
  </tr>
```

Based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37797024/10291167

Comment: Theoretically it's logical but practically displays the same result. I think a little CSS will always be required to make this span

Comment: Well, with this code i have the same result as you are trying to achieve w/o CSS ugly hacks. Have you removed your `position:absolute` and all the rest irrelevant styles? Upd: the codepen for you: https://codepen.io/JaredSpb/pen/RwxPjzo

Comment: Btw FF and chrome display this pretty different. For a Chrome you have to control `td` heights to achieve the effect.

Comment: that must be the case then cuz I'm using chrome

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to achieve what was required through some CSS (absolute positioning, margin and padding) but still can't figure out how to do this using only the concepts of HTML. Btw this was a class assignment and our instructor told us that it can be achieved using nested tables. I am still not able to figure it out but thanks to those who helped

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan=3>Day</th>
    <th colspan=3>Seminar</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=2>Schedule</th>
    <th rowspan=2>Topic</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Begin</th>
    <th>End</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>Monday</td>
    <td style="background-color: #F8F6D1;" rowspan=2>8:00 a.m.</td>
    <td style="background-color:#BFB4F8;" rowspan=2>5:00 p.m.</td>
    <td>Introduction to XML</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=6>Tuesday</td>
    <td style="background-color: #F8F6D1;" rowspan=2>8:00 a.m.</td>
    <td style="background-color: #F8F6D1;" rowspan=2>11:00 a.m.</td>
    <td rowspan=3 style="position: absolute;padding-top:7px;padding-bottom: 7px;padding-right:148px;">XPath</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #F8F6D1;" rowspan=2>11:00 a.m.</td>
    <td style="background-color: #C7F8D8;" rowspan=2>2:00 p.m.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=3 style="position: absolute;padding-top: 7px;padding-bottom: 7px;padding-right:50px;margin-top: 10px;">XSL Transformations</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #C7F8D8;" rowspan=2>2:00 p.m.</td>
    <td style="background-color:#BFB4F8;" rowspan=2>5:00 p.m.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td style="background-color: #F8F6D1;">8:00 a.m.</td>
    <td style="background-color: #C7F8D8;">12:00 p.m.</td>
    <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
  </tr>

</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `position: absolute` trick is quite nasty though :p. It will break as soon as there are any text/layout changes.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by nested table...

```
<table border width='300' height='200'>
      <tr>
        <td width='150'>Data 1</td>
        <td rowspan="3">
          <table width="150" height='100%'>
            <tr>
              <td>Nested 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Nested 2</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found this solution. But it turned out to be a weird table.
The "rhythm" of two-to-three can only be realised by internally working with 6 rows. This is what I did below. The cell

```
<td rowspan=3>XPath<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</td>
```

was made to look a little taller by adding a few `<br>`s.

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan=3>Day</th>
    <th colspan=3>Seminar</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=2>Schedule</th>
    <th rowspan=2>Topic</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Begin</th>
    <th>End</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>Monday</td>
    <td style="background-color: #F8F6D1;" rowspan=2>8:00 a.m.</td>
    <td style="background-color:#BFB4F8;" rowspan=2>5:00 p.m.</td>
    <td>Introduction to XML</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=6>Tuesday</td>
    <td rowspan=2 style="background-color: #F8F6D1;">8:00 a.m.</td>
    <td rowspan=2 style="background-color: #F8F6D1;">11:00 a.m.</td>
    <td rowspan=3>XPath<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2 style="background-color: #F8F6D1;">11:00 a.m.</td>
    <td rowspan=2 style="background-color: #C7F8D8;">2:00 p.m.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td rowspan=3>XSL Transformations</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2 style="background-color: #C7F8D8;">2:00 p.m.</td>
    <td rowspan=2 style="background-color:#BFB4F8;">5:00 p.m.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td style="background-color: #F8F6D1;">8:00 a.m.</td>
    <td style="background-color: #C7F8D8;">12:00 p.m.</td>
    <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```